# Configure rails from external gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loggly

I am trying to configure my rails application from an external gem. Trying to build a central gem for handling logging related things.I am setting few loggly configs and trying to add custom params in loggly inspired from this post- [Custom data to logs](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge/issues/94)

```
module Bizlogger
    class Railtie < Rails::Railtie # :nodoc:
      initializer 'bizlogger.configure_rails_initialization' do
        config = app.config

        Rails.application.configure do
          require 'syslogger'
          config.lograge.enabled = true
          config.lograge.custom_payload = proc do
            {
                host: request.host,
                user_id: current_user.try(:id),
                fwd: request.remote_ip
            }
            end
        end
        app.middleware.insert_before Rails::Rack::Logger, Bizlogger::Middleware,
                                       {}
      end

      def app #:nodoc:
        Rails.application
      end
    end
  end
```

But I am getting NoMethodError when i am including this gem in my application

```
/home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `lograge' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000003959040> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: seems like your railtie is loaded before lograge's one

Comment: @Aleksey how do i control that ?

Comment: right now I am not sure how. I would try to remove `app` method and pass `app` to `initializer` block (like here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html). and also why do you have `Rails.application.configure`? is it required?

Comment: @Aleksey if i put same configs in my development.rb then it is working fine.

Comment: in `development.rb` you need `configure` method but in railtie I think there is no need. right now I need to go. I will check this question few hours later.

Comment: @Aleksey Thanks for pointing it out. It worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124103/discussion-between-aleksey-and-rakesh-yadav).